# Random Word SetGetGo API

Tags: python, json, api, rest

I am creating an application using Python 3 that retrieve a random word from the following API service,

http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php

This is what I have done so far,

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php')
```

I tried

```
word = response.read()
print (word)
```

But all I'm getting is,

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbfcellepore\r\n'
b'\xef\xbb\xbfchough\r\n'
b'\xef\xbb\xbfparamide\r\n'
b'\xef\xbb\xbfunsiphon\r\n'
b'\xef\xbb\xbfadenopodous\r\n'
b'\xef\xbb\xbfsupertramp\r\n'
b'\xef\xbb\xbfEphraimite\r\n'
b'\xef\xbb\xbfosteostracan\r\n'
b'\xef\xbb\xbfrhizopodan\r\n'
b'\xef\xbb\xbftransiter\r\n'
b'\xef\xbb\xbfoneirocritically\r\n'
```

The API service said it'll return JSON, but that doesn't look like JSON.

I was wondering if there's something wrong with my code or the API service isn't working as intended.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the service is not returning JSON. As you can see, it returns that plain text and sets the Content-Type header to text/html, regardless of whatever we send on the Accept header:

```
>>> req = urllib2.Request('http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php', headers={"Accept": "application/json"})
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> word = response.read()
>>> word
'\xef\xbb\xbfNinevitish\r\n'
>>> response.headers['Content-Type']
'text/html'
```

Since the service is poorly documented, it's hard to tell what's going on and what it actually expects. The `\xef\xbb\xbf` prefix is an UTF-8 BOM, so if you still want to use it like that, you can do something like:

```
>>> word.decode('utf-8-sig').strip()
u'Ninevitish'
```